# R Shiny Leaflet addLegend() Specify label order

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Given the following example data

```r
mydata <- data.frame(
  lat = c(21.05939, 21.04305, 21.05977, 21.04336, 21.04434),
  lng = c(92.22692 ,92.23357 ,92.22733 ,92.23361 ,92.23478),
  X1 = c("sometimes", "always", "never", "often", "rarely")
)
```

And the following Leaflet plot:

```r
pal1 <- c("#003366","#00ced1", "#ffd700","#ffa500","#ff1a1a")
color <- colorFactor(pal1, domain = mydata$X1)

leaflet(data = mydata) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lng = mydata$lng, 
                   lat = mydata$lat,
                   color = ~color(mydata$X1)) %>%
  addLegend("topright",
            pal=color,
            values=mydata$X1,
            opacity = 1)
```

[image]

How can I manipulate the order of labels in the legend so that they are:
always,
often,
sometimes,
rarely,
never

I have attempted to specify the `levels` argument in `colorFactor()` and have also attempted the same with the `values` argument in `addLegend` However, the legend still resorts to alphabetical order of the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NVM I think I figured it out.
I first specified a sort order by:

```
sort_val = factor(mydata$X1, levels = c('always',
                            'often',
                            'sometimes',
                            'rarely',
                            'never'))
```

I then passed `sort_val` to the `values` argument in `addlegend()`

```r
  addLegend("topright",
            pal=color,
            values=sort_val,
            opacity = 1)
```

I think this is correct unless anyone can suggest an alternative?